# Finding a circle within a circle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, path, subgraphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be undirected, and let $s,t\in V$ and $C\subseteq E$ be a circle that contains $s$ and $t$. Assuming $s$ and $t$ are on the circle $C$, we are given a set of edges $F\subseteq E$ which are to be removed. After removing these edges, we want to verify whether the remaining edges from the circle $C(F) = C \backslash F$ have a subcircle $C^{'} \subseteq C(F)$ that contains both $s$ and $t$.

If the circle $C$ is known to be simple, the answer is quick. If $C\cap F \neq \emptyset$ the answer is false, there is no subcircle, let alone one that contains $s$ and $t$.

I'm having trouble to see how one can verify whether such a subcircle exists in the case where $C$ is not a simple circle. I tried locating subcircles that have been hit by $F$ and thus cannot be used, but its seems every rule I try to make has a counterexample.

Edit: Running an $s,t$-flow is too expensive, perhaps there is a faster way, as this was a circle.

Comment: You're right, I'm trying to find a way that is more efficient than running max flow, perhaps somehow utilizing this is a circle. I will update the question.

Comment: Why $s,t$ flow is expensive? You simply have to run the Ford Fulkerson algorithm. It only performs DFS twice. So the running time is $O(|V| + |E|)$, for the graph spanned by $C(F)$. Since $C(F)$ might not always be a simple cycle, I think you must have to DFS/BFS at least once. So I think flow solution is asymptotically best.

Comment: Since this question is not particularly centric to computer science (even though your application of it might be), there exists a larger graph-theory community over at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory that might also help even more with this question.

Comment: What do you mean by a "circle"?  Do you mean a "cycle"?  What is a "subcircle"?  Please [edit] your question accordingly.